# How to get the value/index of the highlighted (not selected) item of a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm writing a C# WinForms application. On my form, I have 2 ComboBoxes. `combobox1` is filled with a list of last names and `combobox2` will be filled with the corresponding first names.

When I open the drop down in `combobox1` and just use the up and down arrows or move the mouse cursor over the items, I need to get a value to show in `combobox2` that is related to the highlighted item in `combobox1`. I tried using the `SelectedIndex` property, but that only works when I select an item in `combobox1` *rather than highlighting it*.

I tried searching for a solution, but couldn't find something useful.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e234c4a7-0cf7-4284-a072-8152f7593002/combobox-item-highlight-event?forum=winforms) might help.

Comment: However, it's not common, not practical ***(and not expected by the user)*** to set the corresponding value in a linked ComboBox before actually selecting a value in the first one. You might consider using a [`ListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/listbox-control-windows-forms) control instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use, OnDataBound event something similar to this.
http://codingboys.blogspot.in/2012/11/show-tooltip-in-aspnet-dropdownlist.html